# VBA Code to delete macro automatically opening when the file opens

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master file that opens a user form automatically when started, lets users select options and then saves the file as a new version modified based on these selections. The code that initiates this action is assigned to ThisWorkbook Object. I would like this version not to contain the macro that opens the form at the beginning. Is there a way to erase this part of the code when the new version is being saved?

Comment: Save the file as xlsx, not xlsm. All macros will then be stripped.

Comment: If  you don't need any of the code, you could save the copy as Macro-free file (.xlsx). Else, you could add a simple check for the filename, and only if it is the original file execute the rest. Don't try to tinker around with trying to remove the code at all (if you are interested, search for *VBE*)

Comment: I want the file to contain the rest of the code but the name check works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to perform a check before running any code.  This won't strip out the code, it will just stop it from running.

The check could be the name of the workbook or a value in a cell

eg

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If ThisWorkbook.Name <> "MyMacroWorkbook.xlsx" Then Exit Sub
    'current code here
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HiddenWorksheet").Cells(1, 1).Text <> "RunMyMacro" Then Exit Sub
    'current code here
End Sub
```

The other method is to modify the VBA code, but this is dangerous and normally blocked in most organisations as it is potentially very dangerous.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I implemented based on the comments above